# Android - Display FCM notification message in Listview onClicking Notification

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have successfully sent Firebase notifications using my own server to Android app and I am listing the messages in a ListView in a new activity by clicking the notification. My issue is if I click on one particular notification, all unread notification messages are getting displayed in ListView.

FirebaseMessageservice.java:

```
private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
    //optionally we can display the json into log
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
    try {
        //getting the json data
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");


        //parsing json data
        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        list.add(message);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        System.out.println(list);

        MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        //if there is no image
        if(imageUrl.equals("null")){
            //displaying small notification
            mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);
        }else{
            //if there is an image
            //displaying a big notification
            mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(title, message, imageUrl, intent);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

> HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_list);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Output Screens

If i click on Hello Mom, It moves to next activity with `listview` but with both messages are getting displayed "1. Mom 2. Dad"

[image]

[image]

Comment: in your list have 2 item so it shows

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar .Yes i understand. But i need to show only mom in listview if i click on mom - notification. I have to display dad and mom in listview if i click on dad. Likewise the list goes on.

Comment: from where the list is coming like mom and dad

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar It is coming from notification body. If i click on notification which contains the message "mom" , Message has to transfer to next activity and should be printed in listview. I am sending notification from an android app using my own server code written in php